# Tag merge request: [sharepoint] and [sharepoint-api]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Most people are already posting their questions under [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint) (10,342 at this time) while [sharepoint-api](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-api) has only a few (167 at this time).  I have missed examining some questions because I just noticed that the [sharepoint-api](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-api) tag even existed.

Questions under the [sharepoint-api](/questions/tagged/sharepoint-api) tag would probably get more attention if they were merged into [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint) or if they became tag synonyms.

Comment: Holy crap the [tag:sharepoint] tag is a honeypot of crap questions.

Comment: Welcome to the glorious world of SharePoint...

Comment: If I were asking a question about managing sharepoint (incorrectly on SO, of course) I'd tag it Sharepoint.  If I was asking about extending sharepoint, I'd tag it sharepoint-api.  So I don't think this is a good idea.  I think its a better one to go through the sharepoint tag and either migrate or close as off topic as much as possible.

Comment: @Won't So are you suggesting keeping the sharepoint-api tag and getting rid of the sharepoint one?

Comment: @skeletank: If anything, yeah.

Comment: @Won't: I'm all up for that.  I just think that there should be a single sharepoint tag.